# Low performance of NodeJS RunInContext on Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: node.js

I wrote a very simple HTTP server with NodeJS running on AWS EC2. But only 10% percent of the CPU can be used with heavy request. I'm wondering why?

```
const { runInNewContext, createContext } = require('vm');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  await runInNewContext(
    ``, // empty code
    {}, // empty context
    {
      timeout: 300, // but with default timeout
    });
  res.write('Hello, World!\n');
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:8080');
});
```

Comment: What instance type are you using? You might have selected a burstable instance type which consumes CPU credits, and you are running out of.

Comment: I found it it is because the "timeout" parameter. When I removed it, the http server becomes very fast.